# How to select rows based on column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have following data :

```
Activity :

UserId  Activity    ClassId
1       1           NULL        
NULL    1           1
1       2           NULL
NULL    2           1   
NULL    3           1
```

Expected Result:

```
Activity :

UserId  Activity    ClassId
1       1           NULL        
1       2           NULL
NULL    3           1
```

I am trying to select user records , if it is not exist then need to select from class :

```
 var userId = 1;
 var classId = 1;
 var result = activity.where(a=> a.UserId == userId || a.ClassId == classId).select(a=> a).ToList();
```

Incorrect Result :

```
Activity :

UserId  Activity    ClassId
1       1           NULL        
NULL    1           1
1       2           NULL
NULL    2           1   
NULL    3           1
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since you have or filter for both userid and classid as Or, so records come for both

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which record is returned in this case, then doing a simple FirstOrDefault() will return the first record of the two.

```
var result = activity.Where(a => a.UserId == userId || a.ClassId == classId).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you prefer the record with the non-null UserId returned first, and in a single line of code, you can sort by that column descending, and then get the first or default:

```
var result = activity.Where(a => a.UserId == userId || a.ClassId == classId).OrderByDescending(a => a.UserId).FirstOrDefault()
```

**EDIT:**
To get them as they are in 'expected result', we want to first sort by UserId descending, then group by activity, then select the first within the group. Because we sorted initially, the first will always be the activity with UserId populated, unless none exists:

```
var result = activity.Where(a => a.UserId != null ? a.UserId == userId : a.ClassId == classId).OrderByDescending(a => a.UserId).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I need all activities as expected result.

Comment: @furqanms I've updated my answer to account for that, please see if it meets your expectations.

Comment: No, it will not work. I need all the activities and the condition you have made will return activity from the class in case User has activity defined. In this case I don't need the activity from the class